WPforms not able to get pass entering password
First time poster so sorry if I format this wrong.
Here's what's up. I have a WP site that needs one page password protected. The page also has a WPform on it and the client want's it behind a password.
When I set the page to private (and a child page to the former page) it gets stuck in a password loop. The password page comes up but it just loops back to asking the password infinitely.
What I've tried:

Removing password protection and updating

Changing the password to something else

Recreating the page entirely (in case something was there I didn't see)

Anything else I could think of.


I am a baby coder and learning by fire so I'm hoping someone here has some experience with this and can help me. (Again, sorry for the crap formatting, I'm super new to this.)
